# Programmatic way to build a hal+json from a list with certain object in spring-rest / Jackson

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-rest

For testing purposes im searching for a elegant and less error prune way to build a hal+json data structure based on a Java list of certain objects.

Currently im using a quite huge ugly String for mapping/defining a expected hal+json data structure. I could place this of course also into a file but still imho its a bit error prune. As soon as a object/property would change i also would need to change my hard coded hal+json string/file...

Does anybody knows a helper class or something what could help to build the hal+json based on Java objects?

Answer (score 0):

Spring [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/) helps you with generation of hal+json response .

you have to take care of following configuration

1. on any spring configuration class add  **@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = { HypermediaType.HAL })**

2.make sure that you have Jackson library on classpath

3.Java object extends ResourceSupport or you wrap java object around Resource.
more details on [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.20.x/reference/html/#fundamentals.resources)

4.This should generate hal+json response.

5.Add specific links to resource like self , to other resources .

Please [click](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.20.x/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links) here for more details on Links